# process.env environment variable undefined

Tags: reactjs, typescript, environment-variables, backstage

I am trying to access an environment variable through process.env in my React/Typescript code, but it's returning undefined. I am able to access `NODE_ENV` though.

```
console.log(process.env.CURRENT_URL) // prints "undefined" on browser
```

```
console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV) // prints "development" on browser
```

`CURRENT_URL` is present in windows environment variable.

Why is `process.env.NODE_ENV` is accessible but not the other variable?

Comment: Are you using create-react-app?

Comment: Looks like whatever React framework you are using defines NODE_ENV by default while you are doing something wrong to define your custom environment variables.

Comment: It’s a plugin in https://backstage.io/ app. I can access CURRENT_URL in node through command line . The issue is happening  inside the code only.

Answer (score 10):

This is your [answer](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/), from the official create-react-app docs.

Summary:
By default you will have `NODE_ENV` defined for you, and any other environment variables starting with `REACT_APP_`.

So prepend `REACT_APP_` to all your env variables e.g. `REACT_APP_CURRENT_URL`.
That should work!

Answer (score 3):

As you are on a `react` project, you would have to prepend the env variables with `REACT_APP_`.

You can follow those steps:

- Provide a variable in your .env file which start with `REACT_APP_` (e.g: `REACT_APP_MY_VAR`).
- Then, in your code, you can get it using process.env (e.g: `process.env.REACT_APP_MY_VAR`).

Example:

Define the variables in `.env` file

```
REACT_APP_PASSWORD=1234
REACT_APP_LANGUAGE=english
```

How to use the `environment variables`?

```
console.log(process.env.REACT_APP_LANGUAGE);

// output: english
```

Don't forget to restart the application when you add a new environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this package to defined the process env

[cross-env](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env)

Answer (score 0):

The issue was being caused by backstage software configuration, which was blocking the frontend plugin from accessing variables.  I had to explicitly expose the variables to my frontend plugin using - [*backstage* visibility keyword](https://backstage.io/docs/conf/defining#visibility)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem also but when I restart(with `npm start`) my project it works!

Try restarting your application:

```
npm start
```